# Changing Page default namespace in XAML pages

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xml-namespaces, xamarin.forms

I wanted to change the base class of all pages in my project. To do so, I've made a class which inherits from `ContentPage` and then in all pages I should add the namespace of the `BasePage` that I've made like so:

```
       xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MyApp.Pages;assembly=MyApp"
```

and change the default tag of the page

```
      <pages:PageBase xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
```

**My question is**, Can't we put the namespace of the `BasePage` somewhere like `app.config` in order not to repeat it for each page?

Comment: you can probably edit the new xaml page template to include your namespace, but I doubt you can easily change the default NS.

Comment: @Jason: Actually I'm not trying to change the default namespace, I'm just trying to define a global NS for all pages.

Comment: Would be a very nice feature, I'm on the same boat, but no, there's no way to do that.

Comment: Have a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111911/A-Guide-to-Cleaner-XAML-with-Custom-Namespaces-and).